# ¿Cómo escalar una imagen png con transparencia?

Tags: php

Debo implementar una clase en PHP 5.6 donde debo escalar imágenes jpeg/jpg, png y gif (obviamente la imagen conserva su formato original) . Sin embargo, la imagen png debe conservar la transparencia del fondo en caso de tenerla.

Hasta ahorita, puedo escalar las imágenes pero no puedo conservar el fondo transparente de la imagen original, en su defecto, el color de fondo se vuelve negro.

¿Alguien puede darme una idea de cómo conservar el fondo transparente?

En cuanto al código, hice lo siguiente:

```
( $imagen_tipo ){
    case "image/jpg":
    case "image/jpeg":
        $imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg( $archivo );
        break;
    case "image/png":
        $imagen = imagecreatefrompng( $archivo );
        break;
    case "image/gif":
        $imagen = imagecreatefromgif( $archivo );
        break;
}
$lienzo = imagecreatetruecolor( $miniatura_ancho, $miniatura_alto );//Crea el fondo donde se colocará la imagen
imagecopyresampled($lienzo, $imagen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $miniatura_ancho, $miniatura_alto, $imagen_ancho, $imagen_alto);//Copia y cambia el tamaño de parte de una imagen redimensionándola
if($imagen_tipo == "image/jpg" || $imagen_tipo =="image/jpeg"){
    imagejpeg($lienzo, $path.$formatoYNombreImagen[0]."-".$heighTamano[$i].".".$formatoYNombreImagen[1], 80);
}else if( $imagen_tipo == "image/png" ){
    imagepng($lienzo, $path.$formatoYNombreImagen[0]."-".$heighTamano[$i].".".$formatoYNombreImagen[1], 80);
}else if ($imagen_tipo == "image/gif"){
    imagegif($lienzo, $path.$formatoYNombreImagen[0]."-".$heighTamano[$i].".".$formatoYNombreImagen[1], 80);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

antes de usar la función imagecopyresampled() creo que deberías setear el blending a falso y setear imagesavealphachannel a true y agregar un par de cosas más.

```
    ( $imagen_tipo ){
        case "image/jpg":
        case "image/jpeg":
            $imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg( $archivo );
            break;
        case "image/png":
            $imagen = imagecreatefrompng( $archivo );
            break;
        case "image/gif":
            $imagen = imagecreatefromgif( $archivo );
            break;
    }
    $lienzo = imagecreatetruecolor( $miniatura_ancho, $miniatura_alto    );//Crea el fondo donde se colocará la imagen
    imagealphablending($lienzo, false);
    imagesavealpha($lienzo,true);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($lienzo, 255, 255, 255, 127);
    imagefilledrectangle($lienzo, 0, 0, $miniatura_ancho, $miniatura_alto, $transparent);
    imagecopyresampled($lienzo, $imagen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $miniatura_ancho, $miniatura_alto, $imagen_ancho, $imagen_alto);//Copia y cambia el tamaño de parte de una imagen redimensionándola
    if($imagen_tipo == "image/jpg" || $imagen_tipo =="image/jpeg"){
        imagejpeg($lienzo, $path.$formatoYNombreImagen[0]."-".$heighTamano[$i].".".$formatoYNombreImagen[1], 80);
    }else if( $imagen_tipo == "image/png" ){
        imagepng($lienzo, $path.$formatoYNombreImagen[0]."-".$heighTamano[$i].".".$formatoYNombreImagen[1], 80);
    }else if ($imagen_tipo == "image/gif"){
        imagegif($lienzo, $path.$formatoYNombreImagen[0]."-".$heighTamano[$i].".".$formatoYNombreImagen[1], 80);
    }
```

Todo esto último funciona si la opacidad del fondo transparente es igual a 0. Si es distinta de 0 va a seguir.

**EDIT**: esta es una traducción de una respuesta realizada por el usuario Dycey. Gracias por la información.

Comment: no hace falta que copies todo el código si solo vas a cambiar algunas lineas.

Comment: Mi intención nunca fue adjudicarme la respuesta a mí. No tengo problema en aclararlo.

Comment: No estas entendiendo. La respuesta esta bien, solo que si solo vas a cambiar algunas lineas, solo podes poner las lineas que cambiaste y aclarar. No hace falta copiar todo el código si solo son algunas lineas que cambiaste. La respuesta esta bien. :)

Comment: Ahh, ahora entiendo! Gracias por el consejo

Comment: muchas gracias, sin embargo ahora me marca lo siguiente:
Warning: imagepng(): gd-png error: compression level must be 0 through 9

saben a que se debe?

Comment: Olvidenlo, ya pude solucionarlo.

Muchas por la ayuda. En verdad me sirvió demasiado.

Comment: @AlexisKatelaars, si esta respuesta te sirvió y fue de ayuda, por favor, considera puntuarla y marcarla como respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Mucho mas fácil es agregando estas lineas:

```
imagesavealpha($gdImage, true);
imagealphablending($gdImage, true);
```

Debajo del:

```
$gdImage = imagecreatefrompng($logo);
```